# Websocket connection error in ionic2 app

Tags: angular, websocket, ionic2

I'm trying to build a hybrid app with Ionic2 and Angular 2. 
While running app first I got error

> SecurityError: The operation is insecure.

So I changed `ws` to `wss` in **ion-dev.js** file

```
this.socket = new WebSocket('ws://' + window.location.hostname + ':' + IonicDevServerConfig.wsPort);
```

Now I'm getting error

> Firefox can’t establish a connection to the server at wss://...

Comment: Do you have a web socket server running under the `${window.location.hostname:IonicDevServerConfig.wsPort}`? The port is specified by the web socket server

Comment: This is actual error error shown by Firefox .Firefox can’t establish a connection to the server at wss://angular5-pmache.c9users.io:53703/.. I've server running onhttps://angular5-pmache.c9users.io/

Comment: Okey, sorry for asking but i want to make sure: Do you know under which port is Web Socket is running ? Yesterday I was fighting with something similar locally. I have a node.js local and angular 4 running. I expose the WS port from the node.js and angular fetches it `this.http.get(this.portURL)` and inside the promise `this.url = location.origin.replace(/^http/, 'ws');`  
`if (location.origin.includes('localhost')) {
          this.url = this.url.replace('4200', '5000');
        } else {
          this.url = this.url.replace('4200', this.port.toString());
        }`

Comment: When server is started message displayed is Starting app-scripts server: --address 0.0.0.0 --port 8080 --livereload-port 
35729 --dev-logger-port 53703 --nobrowser. but ionic is displaying message at the end        Local: http://localhost:8080
     External: http://172.17.0.28:8080
     DevApp: gitSearch@8080 on pmache-angular5-5662672

Comment: Maybe you are trying to connect to "dev port" `IonicDevServerConfig.wsPort` all the time and on production the port is different. That was at least my issue with heroku. How do you "bundle" web socket server in an ionic app ? 

EDIT: That is why i replace '4200' (local hot reload port for angular) with whatever the server is telling sending via GET method on prod

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue (Heroku, Angular for front-end, Node.js Web socket server)

What worked for me recently: 
OnInit

```
this.http.get(this.portURL)
      .toPromise()
      .then((res: any) => {
        const json = res.json();
        this.port = json.port;
        console.log(`port ${this.port}`);

        this.url = location.origin.replace(/^http/, 'ws');
        if (location.origin.includes('localhost')) {
          this.url = this.url.replace('4200', '5000');
        } else {
          this.url = this.url.replace('4200', this.port.toString());
        }

        this.initWebSocketConnection();
        console.log(`url ${this.url}`);
      })
      .catch((reason) => {
        console.log(reason);
      });
```

In node.js

```
const express = require('express');
const socketIO = require('socket.io');
const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;
...
const server = express().get('/port', (req, res) => {
    res.json({port: port})
  })
.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Listening on ${port}`)
  });
...

const io = socketIO(server);
```

`io.on(// io staff here ... )`

In this way I managed to run node.js app locally and angular locally. My file structure is like this: root project is a simple node.js-express app and inside there a have a view folder which includes the angular app.